# why php files must be stored in htdocs folder when using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

why we have to store php files in htdocs foler in XAMPP? i can assume this is something related to the parser used in XAMPP. but i just like to know what exactly is the reason. why such a restriction exists

Comment: It's not a restriction, you can place php files anywhere if you change your vHost.

Comment: I dont use XAMPP personally but its most likely to be how XAMPP sets up its apache config files as its apache that actually serves your website. This is not a restriction just simply a standard setup from XAMPP.

Try having a look at the httpd.conf or vhost.conf files within the XAMPP apache folders to change the location its has setup for your files.

Generally you will find most hosting services use either a htdocs or public_html folder to have all website files.